# Books, Parts, and Prologues

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir

I'm trying to nicely format a fairly large novel, with the following structure:

```
Preamble
Prologue
Book I
    Part I
        Chapter 1
            ...
(etc.)
Epilogue
Postamble
```

I'm using memoir and everything looks quite nice, but for the fact that I don't know how to print a pretty page for "Prologue", "Epilogue", or any of the headers for the Books. Memoir is pretty smart about the Chapters and Parts, is there any higher level of structure for things like Prologues/Epilogs and or structure at the super-part level?

For reference, here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{demo}
\chapter*{Preamble}
    Preamble
\chapter*{Prologue}
    Prologue

\chapterstyle{default}
\chapter*{Book I}
\newpage
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \part{Part I}
        \chapterstyle{hangnum}
        \chapter{Chapter 1}
            Chapter 1
\end{document}
```

I am in no way attached to this layout and it's trivial for me to change, I just want it to look nice in the end. So far this is a decent solution, but I was wondering if there were a better / more intelligent way to do it.

Currently the largest problem with this layout is that I haven't figured out how to have the chaptermark be `Prologue` instead of `CHAPTER 0. PROLOGUE`, in the prologue, but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Have you considered using `\chapter*` (instead of `\chapter`) for your `Preamble`, `Prologue`, etc.?

Comment: Yep! My next question would be "how do I turn off the CHAPTER 0. CHAPTERNAME" marker in the headings, but I'm currently picking my way through the manual to find out. If you could point me in the right direction that would save me quite a bit of time. :-)

Comment: How about editing your existing post with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (stripping all the unnecessary stuff) so that it shows what you've done thus far, since many things can influence what you do in your document and where.

Comment: When using `\chapter*` (as in your MWE), I don't receive a header `CHAPTER 0. PROLOGUE`. If you're getting this in your header, you must be doing something else. Also, using `\chapter*` does not increment the `chapter` counter, leaving it at `0`, which it finally incremented at the first use of `\chapter{Chapter 1}`. As such, you don't need to set it to `0` (`\setcounter{chapter}{0}`). Moreover, the commands `\endpart` and `\endchapter` are not recognized control sequence in LaTeX nor `memoir`.

Comment: Woops, just fixed the chapter problems. In the MWE there is no chapter marker, because the only chapter marker I can get is CHAPTER 0. PROLOGUE (by using \chaptermark{Prologue}). The desired behavior is to have the header just be "PROLOGUE", which I'm working on now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're after, but this is too long for a comment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}

\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}

\chapterstyle{demo}
\chapter*{Preamble} \chaptermark{Preamble}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter*{Prologue} \chaptermark{Prologue}
\lipsum[11-20]

\chapterstyle{default}
\chapter*{Book I}
\cleardoublepage

\makeatletter
\createmark{part}{left}{shownumber}{\partname\ }{. \ }
\createmark{chapter}{right}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\makeatother
\part{Part I}
\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

The use of `\createmark{<sec>}{<pos>}{<show>}{<before>}{<after>}` is probably what you're after in terms of headings. It creates a mark for the sectional unit `<sec>` (like `chapter`, for `\chapter`) which is displayed on `<pos>` pages (where `<pos>` is `left`, `right` or `both`). `<show>` can either be `shownumber` or `nonumber` if you want to display the number of the sectional unit in the mark, while `<before>` is placed *before* the number and `<after>` is placed *after* the number.

In my MWE, I used

```
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }
```

to place the `\chapter` mark on `both` pages with a chapter number (`shownumber`). The number is prepended with `\@chapapp\` (which defaults to `Chapter\`) and appended with `.\`, followed by the chapter name.

Read more about how to set page styles and headers in the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (section **7.2 Page styles**, from p 118).

The use of [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is merely used to provide some dummy text to fill the document.