# Prologue with Chapter Title

Tags: numbering, chapters

I am completely new to LaTex and I'm trying to learn it to format a novel. I am using the memoir class.

Through researching, I found I can do this:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
```

To accomplish this:
[image: Chapter One]

I have a Prologue, though, and that prologue has a title. I can suppress the number using:

```
\chapter*{Storms and Shadows}
```

But I don't know how to insert the word PROLOGUE into the chapter number spot. I tried changing the chapter mark as mentioned in [this sectioning answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38756/229516), but I must be doing something wrong because it isn't working. Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Maybe just `\chapter*{\centering -- PROLOGUE --\\ your title}`

Comment: @Nico, you are a genius. That worked. Would you consider posting it as an answer so I can mark it and give you the credit?

Comment: Sure, I've added an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work here with a simple line break in the title to achieve what you want. To avoid numbering we use the asterisk-form `\chapter*{}`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{\centering -- PROLOGUE --\\ yout title}
\end{document}
```

[image]